# Countdown timer not counting down in by 1 second - Jquery/Javascript

Tags: jquery, timer, countdown

I'm 3 weeks new into Javascript and 2 days into Jquery.  I'm having a problem with my countdown timer...

I want it to countdown from 30 seconds, when I click 'play', (element ID #play).

When I click play, the countdown timer appears in the correct element ID #countdown, at 29 seconds.

However, it's frozen and just doesn't countdown by 1 second.  I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong!

Any help would be grand.

I've attached the basic html template code.  And the JS I've written.

```js
function init() {


  console.log('hello');

  const $play = $('#play');
  const $countdown = $('#countdown');

  let timeRemaining = 30;
  let timerOn = false;
  let timerId = null; //null is the same as false

  function countDownLogic() {

    if (timeRemaining > 0) {
      --timeRemaining;
      $countdown.html(timeRemaining);
      timerId = setInterval(1000);
      console.log('start timer');

      // IF COUNTDOWN HITS ZERO 
      if (timeRemaining === 0) {
        //$play.classList.remove('hide');
        console.log('time ends');
      } else {
        console.log('false');
      }
    } else {
      timerOn = false;
      clearInterval(timerId);
    }

    $play.html('PLAY AGAIN!');
  }

  $play.on('click', () => {
    if (!timerOn) {
      timerOn = true;
      countDownLogic();
      // timerId = setInterval(countDownLogic(), 1000);
    }
  });

}
$(init);
```

```html
<header>Header</header>


<!-- PLAY BUTTON -->
<div><button id="play">Play</button></div>

<main>


  <section class="desktop section1">
    <div>Drop Movies Here</div>

    <div class="bottom">Take Guess Here</div>
  </section>

  <section class="section2">

    <!-- Form -->
    <div class="box" id='countdown'>
      <p></p>
    </div>


    <div class="box">
      <p>DIV 2</p>
    </div>

    <div class="box">
      <p>DIV 3</p>
    </div>

    <div class="box">
      <p>DIV 4</p>
    </div>

    <div class="box">
      <p>DIV 5</p>
    </div>

    <!-- BOX 3 -->
    <!-- <div class="box-2">
            <p>DIV 3</p>
          </div> -->

  </section>
</main>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to specify a function in the call to `setInterval`. And you shouldn't call this inside the function that repeats, you should call it to start the counter outside.

The argument to `setInterval` should be `countDownLogic`, not `countDownLogic()`. That calls the function immediately, instead of passing a reference to the function to `setInterval`.

```js
function init() {


  console.log('hello');

  const $play = $('#play');
  const $countdown = $('#countdown');

  let timeRemaining = 30;
  let timerOn = false;
  let timerId = null; //null is the same as false

  function countDownLogic() {

    if (timeRemaining > 0) {
      --timeRemaining;
      $countdown.html(timeRemaining);
      console.log('start timer');

      // IF COUNTDOWN HITS ZERO 
      if (timeRemaining === 0) {
        //$play.classList.remove('hide');
        console.log('time ends');
      } else {
        console.log('false');
      }
    } else {
      timerOn = false;
      clearInterval(timerId);
    }

    $play.html('PLAY AGAIN!');
  }

  $play.on('click', () => {
    if (!timerOn) {
      timerOn = true;
      timerId = setInterval(countDownLogic, 1000);
    }
  });

}
$(init);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<header>Header</header>


<!-- PLAY BUTTON -->
<div><button id="play">Play</button></div>

<main>


  <section class="desktop section1">
    <div>Drop Movies Here</div>

    <div class="bottom">Take Guess Here</div>
  </section>

  <section class="section2">

    <!-- Form -->
    <div class="box" id='countdown'>
      <p></p>
    </div>


    <div class="box">
      <p>DIV 2</p>
    </div>

    <div class="box">
      <p>DIV 3</p>
    </div>

    <div class="box">
      <p>DIV 4</p>
    </div>

    <div class="box">
      <p>DIV 5</p>
    </div>

    <!-- BOX 3 -->
    <!-- <div class="box-2">
            <p>DIV 3</p>
          </div> -->

  </section>
</main>
```